# material-ui components | datePicker | no data passed to onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, redux, material-ui

I have a simple form with a **material-ui** `DatePicker`, e.g:

```
<DatePicker name="startDate" autoOk={true} floatingLabelText="startDate" onChange={(x, event) => {console.log(arguments);}} />
```

However, if I change the date, an empty array is printed to the console. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this.

```
"material-ui": "0.15.0"
"react": "15.1.0"
"react-tap-event-plugin": "1.0.0"
"redux": "3.0.5"
"redux-form": "^6.0.0-alpha.4"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is `"arguments"` that you are passing in `console.log()` ?

From the Date Picker documentation in material-ui:

Signature:
function(null: undefined, date: object) => void
null: Since there is no particular event associated with the change, the first argument will always be null.
date: The new date.

Therefore your code becomes:

```
onChange={(event, x) => {console.log(x);}}
```

where `x` is the date.

Hope it helps.

Comment: arguments is an array-like object ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments ) with all arguments passed to the function, for me it is empty, nothing is passed there, as wrote in my question

Comment: so, i'm not sure why, but: `onChange={(event, date) => {console.log(arguments, event, date);}}` returns empty array, null and date. Thanks @antonis-zisis for a hint

Comment: From the documentation: "Arrow functions do not expose an arguments object to their code". https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions (for all it's worth now...)

Comment: It returns undefined with `@material-ui/core`: "^4.11.0"